# Using YTPlayerView automatically start play video

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I use YTPlayerView in UICollectionView, and for some reason when I scroll collection, video start play automatically.
I tried to set property autoplay, but it wasn't helpful.

I assume that somehow scroll triggers tap or something.

Any suggestions would be helpful?

Comment: It's almost impossible to help you without sight of the relevant code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.